# Keyboard mapping on VBox interface

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, vnc, on-screen-keyboard

I installed VBox version 5.22 on server that runs Ubuntu 16.04, when I try to create a Virtual Machine and enter a new name I am observing that the mapping of my keyboard is wrong, e.g., "space" is mapped to "7" . I tried to updated VBox to 6, but it did not help.
The keyboard layout in the system][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34iaz.png)
I noticed that the onboard keyboard (screen keyboard) shows "?" and says "No X Keyboard found, retrying .."

[Onboard keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51EjY.png)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could it be a similar issue as below? 
https://superuser.com/questions/422154/incorrect-keyboard-mapping-on-ubuntu-under-virtualbox

Comment: Thanks @cruellays I saw that earlier mine happens only in VBox, also I did change the keyboard to 101 US but did not help

Answer (score 0):

It seems the keyboard mapping between your physical computer and the virtual machine is not matching.

You can change the keyboard layout on virtualbox, inside your VM, with the following command:

```
sudo setxkbmap de
```

`sudo setxkbmap`: set keyboard mapping, runs as root user.

`de`: for German keyboard. You can change it to your favorite layout code.